# Is there a way to have a Alberti bass not sound like music made by Mozart?

Tags: theory

Every time I hear an Alberti bass nowadays I cannot stop thinking about the movie Amadeus. To me it is so stereotypically Wolfgang I cannot get over it. Is there maybe some other composer who used the device in a non-Wolfgang manner that I can listen to, to get over this?

Comment: Apart from the reservation of identifying the title role of a popular movie  with a  real  composer - don't you consider it a bit harsh concerning even that composer with a huge oeuvre and a toolbox extending far beyond such a simple scheme?

Answer (score 5):

To the "is there a way..." question: yes. In addition to the characteristic Alberti bass, which is common to a very wide swath of classical-era music (Mozart, Clementi, Diabelli, Beethoven, Haydn, Schubert, etc.), there is also the basic musical structure — specifically, tonality.

So taking Alberti bass out of tonality will not sound like Mozart.

For example, here is Shostakovich's Prelude in C Major, Op. 34, No. 1:

The third movement of Prokofiev's Piano Sonata No. 4 features an Alberti bass near the opening.

There's no single composer who one can point to and say that non-Mozartean Alberti bass is characteristic of or common to that composer, but with most any composer, one can probably find Alberti, or Alberti-like, examples.

Comment: Aaron, it's a great and thoughtful answer.  However, I'd classify those modern moments as *nods* to Alberti bass, rather than as actual Alberti bass.  This might be a no-true-Scotsman argument, but that's just how I feel it.

Answer (score 1):

In my own compositions, I've used that fact creatively.  Sometimes, I want to evoke and blend idioms from different eras into a kind of stylistic metamusical style.

I use Alberti bass **because** I want people to think: "Oh, that little bit sounds like Mozart!"  So this is a highly subjective question, but my answer is "no"-- even if a song isn't BY Mozart, you can't have Alberti bass without him coming to mind to some degree. ;D

Answer (score 0):

For starters, try Beethoven's Piano Sonata Op.13.